# How to add richtext (wysiwyg) field to a Magento widget

Tags: magento, tinymce, magento-1.7, richtext

I created a few small widgets for magento. Everything fine, but I can`t seem to figure out how to add a richtext (tinymce wysiwyg) field to my widget.

Only thing I find on this is: "use ‘wysiwyg’ => true" in "$fieldset->addField". But I cannot use this in my custom widget, can I?

I understand that I can use addField to add a field to for example a product or CMS page.

But the only way of adding fields in my custom widget, as far as I know, is by adding parameters in my widget.xml. Other widget I build by following some tutorial returns a button, by using a custom type as parameter:

```
$removeButton = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
        ->setType('button')
        ->setClass('delete')
        ->setLabel($this->__('Remove Image'))
        ->setOnclick('document.getElementById(\''.$element->getId().'\').value=\'\';if(document.getElementById(\''.$element->getId().'_image\'))document.getElementById(\''.$element->getId().'_image\').parentNode.remove()')
        ->setDisabled($element->getReadonly())
        ->setStyle('margin-left:10px;margin-top:7px');
```

But i just can`t figure out how to add a richtext field in either my Widget.xml or my phpfile for the custom type.

What am I missing? Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few related entries here on stackoverflow, try searching if you are still having problem with this. Also, have a look at this brilliant article: http://www.behrendt.io/2013/04/12/using-a-wysiwyg-editor-in-a-magento-widget/
It helped me getting started. I got it working as a plain text field but whenever I turn the field to true WYSIWYG the content is never updated and the AJAX call does not contain the new HTML.

Comment: Link does not work anymore, here's a working mirror: https://web.archive.org/web/20140218032356/http://www.behrendt.io/2013/04/12/using-a-wysiwyg-editor-in-a-magento-widget/